# credentialcache.defaultcredentials returning wrong user credentials

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, authentication

I have a ASP.NET Website (.NET 2 IIS 5.1) running on machine A with Integrated Windows Authentication enabled. It has a user Automation.
When I connect to it from machine B with user 'Ganesh', I am prompted to enter username & password (by IE itself).

CASE 1:
*If I DONT save the credentials using remember my password option:*
I get connected to the website.However later internally I need to connect to a webservice to get some details (via code). To to that, the code first sets the credentials to default credentials.

```
statusService.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

Now here the logged in user 'Ganesh' credentials are passed for some reason. (I found that using logon audits logging at the server)

Hence when I call the service:

```
m_LicenseStatus = statusService.GetLicenseStatus(out m_dNoEvalDays);
```

I get HTTP 401 Unauthorized exception.

CASE 2:
*If I save the credentials using remember my password option:*

'Automation' user credentials are passed & the call is successful.

Hence my question is why do I need to save the credentials? It is a necessity or have I missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted Microsoft about this issue.

Following were the recommendations:

http://blogs.msdn.com/jpsanders/archive/2009/09/03/using-httpwebrequest-with-credential-manager.aspx
I opted for a note to be included in known issues list of my software. Hope this helps.